# PayPal Sandbox 'DoDirectPayment' Error Code 10501

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When I attempt to DoDirectPayment I receive the error code saying I have an Invalid Configuration. Although there is a PayPal employee responding to all of the posts online that someone brings up this issue I can not find an actual fix.

Is there a way to add PayPal Payments Pro from a sandbox account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when you create a pre configured Website Payments Pro account, this should get enabled by default.  However from time to time, there are some issues that cause this not to get enabled.  A couple of options for getting this enabled is either trying to manually toggle it on, or trying to create a new pre configured account and see if it gets enabled on the new one.  If you can provide me the email address for your test sandbox seller account, I can try to toggle it manually on my side for you.

Comment: It is not working on my end at all or I am not doing it properly. The account is finance-facilitator@mathrecovery.org

Comment: Go ahead and try it now.  I have enabled pro on it.

Comment: I don't see this "Pre configured" option when creating an account in the developer.paypal.com site :s

Comment: Log into developer.paypal.com > Applications > Sandbox accounts > Create Account > select the account type as Business (merchant account)